# Scrapy Splash settings: "SPLASH_URL"

Tags: ubuntu, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I have a working instance of scrapy splash spider on my PC. I then migrated it to my linux server. The spider works fine and retrieves results without splash. However for the same websites, when I use the splash (https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash) my spider does not retrieve anything and returns a 404 error. I have nginx and django set up on my server and Im wondering whether that's conflicting with the "SPLASH_URL" settings for splash.

1) I have tried changing the splash url to all of the following:

```
SPLASH_URL = 'http://localhost:8050/'
SPLASH_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:80/
SPLASH_URL = '<server ip>:8050/'
```

I have also changed the ports to 80 and 8050

2) When running curl from my server, I get the following

```
 $ curl http://localhost:80/render.html?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com

 <html>
   <head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
   <body bgcolor="white">
     <center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
     <hr><center>nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu)</center>
   </body>
 </html>
```

What could be causing the 404 error. Splash instructions specify either to set the url to localhost or docker ip if I'm using docker. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Have you enabled `SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware`, `SplashCookiesMiddleware` and `SplashMiddleware`? There's also a `DUPEFILTER_CLASS`, have you set it up as well?

Comment: The issue is that when you start a splash instance and a server the IP to the instance changes it's no longer The Local Host... Dockerized or using splash module stand alone, the internel network mapping is different then if you run a local environment.. quite certain thats the issue.

Comment: If I have a clean ubuntu server, what ip should I provide to get the spider to work?

Answer (score 0):

I just figured this out. Turns out my splash server exited due to some error. Running `docker start <containerId>` fixed the issue